# How to orderly arrange charts in excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, overlap

I have this code but when the VBA copies and pastes the charts on the Excelsheet, the Charts overlap.

Is there a way to arrange them in 1 column without overlapping?

Thank you!

```
Sub Test1()

Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

Worksheets("ChartObjects").ChartObjects.Delete

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Sheet.Name <> "ChartObjects" Then

Sheet.Select
For Each cht In Sheet.ChartObjects

cht.Select
cht.Copy

Sheets("ChartObjects").Select
Range("C5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next

End If
Next Sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Each chartobject has a `.Top` property and a `.height` property. You should be able to formulate a way to align each chart based on these.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `.Top` and `.Left` properties of the cell, and the `.Top` and `.Height` properties of each `ChartObject` to align each successive chart with the previous chart's bottom:

```
Sub foo()
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim newCht As ChartObject
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim chtSht As Worksheet
Dim top As Double
Dim left As Double

'Define the destination worksheet
Set chtSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChartObjects")

'Define the starting parameter for the charts
With chtSht.Range("C5")
    top = .top
    left = .left
End With

'Iterate the sheets in the workbook
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Ignore the chtSheet
    If Not sht.Name = chtSht.Name Then
        'Iterate the charts in each worksheet
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            'Copy the chart
            cht.Copy
            'Paste it in to the destination sheet
            chtSht.Paste
            'Get a handle on the chart we just pasted
            Set newCht = chtSht.ChartObjects(chtSht.ChartObjects.Count)

            'Assign the top location of this chart
            newCht.top = top
            newCht.left = left
            'Add with the height of this chart to determine the "top" for the next chart
            top = newCht.top + newCht.Height

        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! There is some Object-defined error that stops it from working, specifically for cht.Copy command. Do you know why?

Comment: Nope. That's the same method you were using previously without error, right? Does it happen for all charts or just one?  Has something about your file changed?  Perhaps worksheet is protected?

Comment: Application or Object defined error often suggests that a worksheet or range is protected. Could that be the case?

Comment: I have checked but I cannot see to be the case... does it work in your case? have you checked?

Comment: This was giving me errors but what I discovered is that for plots with lots of data, the copy/paste function trips over itself, either not ready to copy immediately after paste or not ready to paste immediately after copy. I put in a one second pause after copy and it worked perfectly.  `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))`